# Match values from 2 tables and get the previous and next value

Tags: match, formula

I have a small problem and just can't get any further.
It is about the following table:
[table_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgkKw.png)

In DATA1 there are numbers under current. Then there is a second table DATA2. There are numbers in 6 columns. I want to find the numbers under current in DATA2 and find the number to the right and left of it and put it in the previous and next columns.

Here is the link to the table (go to sheet "P2_Data"):
[table_link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lPt2ufUrtaq1_p5Fw99alyOvshdb64h4_-PtlhM60Ec/edit#gid=1999841307)

I hope you can help me.

greetings to all

I've managed to do that to some extent with INDEX and MATCH. However, I had to copy the formula down.
I'm looking for a solution where the formula is only in the first cell and expands automatically.

With this formula in C3 till C9:

```
=ArrayFormula(Index(A3:J3;;SUMME(SPALTE(E3:J3)*(B3=E3:J3))+1))
```

And this formula in A3 till A9:

```
=ArrayFormula(Index(A3:J3;;SUMME(SPALTE(E3:J3)*(B3=E3:J3))-1))
```

... I get partial solution. But I want the formula to automatically expand downwards without having to copy it to all cells.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Ist there anybody who can help me? I need a solution for tomorrow...

Comment: Unclear exactly what range resize scenarios you are trying to cover but look into BYROW as it is a start down that path. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en

Comment: thanks for the tip. the spreadsheet will later be very large - about 50000 rows. would the byrow formula work better here, like copying the formula I mentioned to all cells?
I'm an absolute beginner. can you perhaps provide me with a formula that is suitable for my task. that would be great.

Comment: Better is subjective here but something like `=ByRow(A3:J500, Lambda(Rng, Index(Rng,  SUMME(...)-1)))` would allow  you to just change the range in the cell in the to row. Or to make the source range a named range. Untested and typing on phone after midnight but that should give you some direction.

Comment: I don't see DROP in the documentation for Sheets but CHOOSECOLS and FILTER can separate E3:J3 from the rest of the range.

Comment: Hi. Sorry but I don't understand anything. I can do this with BYROW - OK. But what about SUM in your solution. Can you Insert your solution in my sheet - that would help me to understand.

Comment: Can you Insert your solution in my sheet - that would help me to understand.

Comment: Done for Previous. You should be able to figure out Next from there.